# Need an example for using RavenFS with WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ravendb, ravenfs

Trying to implement an artifact store for archiving thousands of large/small files for work. Building a POC using .NET WebAPI with RavenFS to store files.

As a newbie to RavenFS, looking for an example which will help me to redirect large files streams uploaded to REST api to RavenFS without storing them on the web server. While searching found a thread on [mutipartformdatastreamprovider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15842496/is-it-possible-to-override-multipartformdatastreamprovider-so-that-is-doesnt-sa) and memory stream providers. Can someone share an example how to use it with RanvenFS?

Comment: Better to ask on Raven's google group.  This sort of ask is off-topic for StackOverflow.